# Increase number of concurrent shells in PowerShell V2

Tags: powershell

I'd like to increase number of concurrent shells in PowerShell V2.I tried using the following command ,but I got no luck.The error I got is" Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help."
Can someone shine some light?

```
winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxShellsPerUser="50"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases concerning the upper limits of programming structures and the like:
"If you have to ask, you're probably doing it wrong" - TheDailyWTF.com

Comment: Well what if someone _does_ need to work with 50 shell windows at once?

Comment: I realize it's a smart-mass answer, but I stick by the assertion that if you think you need more than 50 shells at one, there's *probably* a better way with less shells.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did not close the connection properly to the shell , and now it works like charm.

Answer (score 4):

That syntax likely will work fine from DOS, but from PowerShell, you'll have to escape some of the characters.  This seems to have worked for me:

```
PS> winrm set winrm/config/winrs `@`{MaxShellsPerUser=`"50`"`}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the wsman provider

```
set-item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxShellsPerUser -value 50
```